# Stocks of mostly gentile owned banks with mostly gentile clients

Tags: halacha, transactions, modern-times, lending-interest-ribbis, yoreh-deah

In Halacha, it is prohibited for Jews to give their money to gentiles to lend at interest to other Jews (Tosefta Bava Metzia 5:8).

However, if a majority gentile-owned bank has a majority gentile clientele, but lends to some Jews with interest, is it permitted for Jews to invest in it?

The reason It may be permitted is if the minority of the clientele are Jews and the minority of the investors are Jews then you can have a Chazaka the ribbit Jewish investors get isn’t from Jewish clients.

Comment: Same question would apply to shops that open on Shabbos or sell milk-and-meat products https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6753/investing-in-halacha/23235#23235

Comment: A good point, and would be relevant to taking a significant share in a bank (and I believe some of the sources in the link discuss the point). However for a retail investor the question is similar, as you can see from the linked answer

Comment: "Chazaka/Rov" wouldn't necessarily help - we know for certain that the bank has Jewish customers who have paid it (and thus its shareholders) interest. A more complex argument would be needed, whereby the interest from Jews is somehow attributed to the non-Jewish shareholders, which is difficult to understand but has been advanced historically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are really asking if Jews can invest in Bank of America or Citibank. As we see, this is indeed the case from many.

din.org [explains](https://din.org.il/en/2020/03/08/owning-stock-in-traife-companies/) why

> According to a number of poskim including R’ M. Feinstein R’ Vozner
> and R’ Y. Belski zt”l, when someone buys stock in a company, if he has
> only a minor percentage of shares in the company, and his “vote” isn’t
> going to make any difference because the company is owned by a
> majority of non- Jewish owners, that it is not considered as if he
> “owns” the company.
>
> Rather it is looked at as merely as a business deal with the company,
> that he invested in the company and is making profit from the company,
> but not from the actual business that the company is doing.
>
> **This issue comes up in a number of areas, for example, regarding stocks in a bank that lends money to Jews with interest**, companies
> that sell food on Pesach, and companies that deal with non-kosher
> food. Although there are other poskim that disagree with this, this is
> the minhag of many.

See [there](https://din.org.il/en/2020/03/08/owning-stock-in-traife-companies/) for further sources.

Comment: For large public companies the argument above holds. However the edited question seems to be specifically about rubbish, and would be relevant for a controlling shareholder

Comment: I don't think the question discusses a controlling shareholder (a "majority gentile-owned " bank) but you are right - it would be very different. Still in practice investing in stock markets is nearly never about controlling positions